# Select2 Dropdown Select Child Categories When Parent is selected

Tags: jquery-select2

Good day!

I'm working in a WordPress website and require some Javascript to allow a select2 dropdown to auto-select child elements when it's associated parent is selected.

For example, if a user selects England, then it needs to auto select the child elements under it.

Here is the current HTML:

```
<select name="tax_input" class="directorist-form-element" 
id="at_biz_dir-location" data-select2-id="at_biz_dir-location">

        <option value="187" selected="" data-select2-id="2">Anywhere in the UK</option>
<option value="161" data-select2-id="18">England</option>
<option value="162" data-select2-id="19">East Midlands (child)</option>
    </select>
```